# Group products are not showing after import

Tags: magento2

I have imported group products.It works fine in admin but products are not showing in frontend.Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Please check following points for Group or parent product.

1. Enable Paroduct : Yes
2. Visibility : Catalog,Search
3. Stock Status : In Stock

Then you can run the below commands.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

Please note that you need to check Associate product also for Enable, In Stock option.

Comment: It's Done but not showing group product in front end.It seems out of stock but admin displays instock status.

Comment: You can check with this link https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-grouped-product-in-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to reindex first:

run all the commands and check

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: It's Done but not showing group product in frontend.

Comment: Product display with 3 condition is_salable true, in stock true,is_available true

your products match this conditions?

please check in your db

Comment: I have checked it's true

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that in the import .csv file I was not including `product_websites` field. Once I started including it (with value of `base`), the products appeared successfully under their corresponding group products (and no cache cleaning or reindexing was needed). You could try that as well.

Also, make sure that your group product contains at least one child product.